# Mailbox item id mismatch between Office.js and Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js

I'm developing an Outlook add-in, in which I grab the mailbox item id and send it to an API. The API uses the Microsoft Graph SDK to fetch the message item by the given id. This scenario worked fine so far, but now I'm struggling with a strange format mismatch between the id I get from Office.js and the id from Graph.

`Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId` returns `...MlPrBwD/Cohwu0F...`

Graph returns `...MlPrBwD-Cohwu0F`

So Office.js returns the id containing `/C` where Graph returns `-C` in it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think that the id returned by `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId` is an EWS item id.

You can convert it to rest/graph item id by using  `Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId`.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much